# viewport on iPad strange behaviour

Tags: ipad, viewport, meta-tags

I'm pulling my hair out about this… I know it has been discussed in many threads, but I couldn't find a solution that works for me.

Different problems in iPad and iPhone

When I use this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=3.0,user-scalable=yes"/>
```

The page displays fine in landscape-mode (on iPhone and iPad)
The page is too wide in portrait-mode and can't be scaled down with pinching

Now (and this is kinda hilarious):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-height, maximum-scale=3.0,user-scalable=yes"/>
```

The difference is width=device-**height** (vs. device-**width**)

The page displays fine on the iPad in landscape- and portrait-mode

The page is too wide on portrait mode on the iPhone, works fine in landscape

When I use `initial-scale=1.0` everything's messed up totally (I read that initial-scale shouldn't be used anyway?)

Does anybody have an explanation for this???

Answer (score 1):

if You use this: this will fix when you load into Landscape and go to Portrait.
fixed width kills it i think, specialy if you have fixed PX min-width included.

```
    // BUG orientation portrait/lanscape IOS //
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) {
var viewportmeta = document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]');
if (viewportmeta) {
    viewportmeta.content = 'width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0';
    document.addEventListener('orientationchange', function () {
        viewportmeta.content = 'width=device-width, minimum-scale=0.25, maximum-scale=1';
    }, false);
  }
}
```

also you can fix it with CSS , like this:

```
/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
 html {zoom:0.75;}
}
```

it will zoom to 0.75 in portrait mode only..

**Can you first test this:**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height,width=device-width">
```